# Copying an Excel shape in higher resolution

Tags: excel, vba

I have an object in Excel that I would like to be pasted as a picture in another tab. The object contains various names in the very small font size ( font size is 2 ).

The piece of code responsible for copy/pasting an image of an object is below.So far, it can only paste the image with text being blurry and unreadable. However when I zoom in to the original shape the text reads fine. I need an image with resolution being high enough to be readable at 326% zoom.

Code:

```
  Dim strMap As String
 'Creating a new image
     strMap = "mapGroup3" 'Name of an object
     Sheets("Maps (Prov)").Select
     ActiveSheet.Shapes(strMap).Copy
     Sheets("Image").Select
     Range("a1").Select
     ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
     'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I've attempted to use .PasteSpecial to specify the format but end up with the following error:

```
 Run-time error '438':
 Object does not support this property or method
```

Code for the error above:

```
 'Creating a new image
 strMap = "mapGroup3"
 Sheets("Maps (Prov)").Select
 ActiveSheet.Shapes(strMap).Copy
 Sheets("Image").Select
 Range("a1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Pictures.PasteSpecial _
 Format:=3, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Comment: Generally, adding an image to an image-control makes for much better resolution. Furthermore, I read a very interesting solution [here](https://robp30.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/improving-the-quality-of-excel-image-export/). I haven't tested it as yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste as picture or image always leads to only pasting the visible pixels. So the quality is optimal for the visible size.

If you needs copying exact the quality as it is in the source, then you should not using paste as but only copy/paste from clipboard:

```
Worksheets("Maps (Prov)").Shapes("mapGroup3").Copy
Worksheets("Image").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Image").Range("D4")
```

Of course this pastes the same kind of object as it is in the source. If you really needs changing the kind of object, for example copying a range of cells and pasting this as picture (image), then there is no other way than making the source big enough before copying. The bigger the source will be the more pixels will be pasted later, the better the quality will be.

Unfortunately this is not as easy as it sounds. For example, if one wants copying a range of cells and pasting this as picture (image) in high quality, this needs making all objects in the range of cells bigger before copying. That is line height, column width, font size .... Then vice versa after copying. And grouped shapes must be ungrouped first, then resized all single group members before copying. Then vice versa after copying.

Comment: Worked perfectly!